# $15a ≡ ca \pmod{25}$, then $15 ≡ c \pmod{25}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For which **numbers** $a$ is it true that if $15a ≡ ca \pmod{25}$, then $15 ≡ c \pmod{25}$?

I know that this means that $a\frac{15-c}{25}=k_1\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\frac{15-c}{25}=k_2\in \mathbb{Z}$, but what must I show?

Comment: I changed (\text{mod}~25) to \pmod{25}.  That is standard.  It automatically generated proper spacing before and after "mod" and puts the parentheses where they should be.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Recall that if $x \mid yz$ and $\text{gcd}(x,y)=1$, i.e., $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime, then $x \mid z$.

Comment: To be "relatively prime" is to be what?

Comment: @Pinsgrair $\gcd(x,y) = 1$.

Comment: @Pinsgrair: "relatively prime" means "$\gcd(x, y) = 1$". "$(x, y)$" above is another notation for the gcd.

Comment: You mean "coprime," yes?

Comment: @user17762 What are your $x$ and $y$ here?

Comment: @user17762 $y=a,~z=15-c,~x=25$, yes? How do you know that $\text{gcd}(x,y)=\text{gcd}(25,a)=1$?

Comment: @Pinsgrair Yes. Relatively prime is another word for co-prime which is another word to mean $\gcd$ is $1$.

Comment: So the answer here is all $a$ which are coprime to $25$, yes?

Comment: @mike4ty4 Don't you mean $\text{gcd}(25,a)$?

Comment: Never mind it is a commutative function.

Comment: @Pinsgrair Yes. The answer here is all $a$'s that are coprime to $25$.